# Unit test - React-redux reducers expected value

Tags: unit-testing, react-redux, reducers

I'm trying to make unit-test for redux reducer. And I would like to know the expected return value.

Currently I expected value to equal:

> <"isConnected": false>

But I received:

> <"0": <"isConnected": true>, "isConnected": false>

I found in the documentation two reducer syntax.
The first return an object:

> <"0": <"isConnected": true>, "isConnected": false>

And the second an array:

> [<"isConnected": false>]

What is the value that should be returned by a correct reducer ?

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.3.2"
  }
}
```

My reducer:

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionsTypes'

const initialState = {
    isConnected : true
};

const appReducer = ( state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.OPEN_CONNECTION :
            return {
                ...state,
                isConnected : true
            };

        case types.CLOSE_CONNECTION :
            return {
                ...state,
                isConnected : false
            };

        default:
            return state
    }
};

export default appReducer;
```

My test:

```
it('appReducer Test', () => {
    expect(appReducer([{isConnected : false}], {type: types.OPEN_CONNECTION})).toEqual({isConnected : true})
})
```

Comment: a) what are you using to test? that syntax looks strange. b) reducers don't follow a convention. you have to check the reducer code to see what its returning. can you post that code here?

Comment: @azium I edited my post. The state object returned by the reducer don't follow a convention either ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received this:

> <"0": <"isConnected": true>, "isConnected": false>

Because i gived initialState as an array in my test:

> [{isConnected : false}]

The correct syntax for the test is:

```
expect(appReducer({isConnected : false}, {type: types.OPEN_CONNECTION})).toEqual({isConnected : true})
```